# Setting up Lambda IAM Policy to access Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I've created a lambda to check for custom logic before signing up a new Cognito user. In creating the IAM Policy for this lambda, what is the correct "Action" and "Resource" I should use here?

I'm following this guide: https://medium.com/@earlg3/using-lambda-aws-cognito-triggers-to-only-allow-auto-verification-to-specific-domain-db2efea79c44

Lambda

```js
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    
    // Configure the email domain that will be allowed to automatically verify.
    var approvedDomain = "approveddomain.com";
    
    // Log the event information for debugging purposes.
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));if (event.request.userAttributes.email.includes('@' + approvedDomain)) {
        console.log ("This is an approved email address. Proceeding to send verification email.");
        event.response.emailSubject = "Signup Verification Code";
        event.response.emailMessage = "Thank you for signing up. " + event.request.codeParameter + " is your verification code.";
        context.done(null, event);
    } else {
        console.log ("This is not an approved email address. Throwing error.");
        var error = new Error('EMAIL_DOMAIN_ERR');
        context.done(error, event);
   }};
```

My best guess so far:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "LambdaSignUp",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "cognito-idp:*",
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:userpool/USER_POOL_ID"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out - turns out there are no special IAM policies needed, since you'd point to this lambda from Cognito's AWS Console.

1. Leave the default IAM Policy (the basic one will include log permissions)
2. Go to User Pools > your pool name > Triggers. Under "Custom Message", select your lambda.

That's it!

Note on the lambda above: If you want to test it, make sure you include the `request` and `UserAttributes` keys in the test event:

```
{
  "request": {
    "userAttributes": {
      "email": "hello@test.com"
    }
  },
  "response": {}
}
```